# Plotly graph display issue when embeded in HTML

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, plotly

So there is this weird issue with Plotly displaying graphs in my HTML webpage that I'm not sure how to solve.
Basically, I have multiple graphs I wish to display on a webpage.
So what I did was:

1. come up with a Plotly graph
2. use `fig.write_html` to write that graph into a HTML file
3. embed it into my website using `<iframe>` and style it.

[And it looks something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJsmK.png)

Now, I need to show multiple of these same graphs, so instead of creating many HTML files, I just used one HTML file and placed all my graphs into divs of their own category. To show the div, I toggle the display of the div using `display:none` and `display:flex` in my JavaScript.

[Here's the issue and I think it's best if I demonstrate it as a gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ar7Sc.gif)

As you can see, the graphs in the second div aren't showing properly. So let's say I refresh the website: if I wait for the webpage to load completely and toggle the display on to show the second graphs, their resolution, positioning and size gets all messed up. And if, without waiting for the webpage to load completely, I toggle to show the second graphs, their positioning and resolution becomes normal, but the first graph gets all messed up.

I'm not sure if by disabling the div, I caused the graphs to not show properly, and I don't really know a workaround. I think this is a bad way to embed graphs into my webpage, but I don't exactly have a lot of time to change it, so let me know a quick fix if there is one. Thanks

Edit: the graphs displays very inconsistently. Sometimes it shows properly but other times it gets all messed up, so I'm not very sure what's going on.

Comment: I want you to try something - load up the page and let it load completely, then click a different graph to get the bad visuals to show, once you see a graph that isn't loaded properly, try to resize the window (make it a little smaller) - does that fix the issue with the graph? (i'm trying to see if the graph re-renders on resize)

Comment: @AsherMoshav Yep, I tried resizing by ctrl and mouse wheel scroll, inspect element and mimic smaller devices and even resized my entire window. The graphs still kept the bad positions and resolutions.

Comment: This is probably related to the fact that the DIVs are not displayed when the graphs are rendered. If you remove the display: none from the divs (just let them all show) - do they all look good?

Comment: @AsherMoshav It is as if they only load properly if you "look" at it load. Like I have three sets of graphs, if I set the first one to active and the third one to active, only the second one (which I'm not looking at) has the visual issues

Comment: @AsherMoshav Oh that's a great idea. So I created a javascript onload which set all the div display to none. And before that I set everything to display flex so show all. So while loading my website looks like crap but after it loads, everything goes to normal. Thanks!

Comment: @AsherMoshav yup, it just looks very messy while its loading the page but after loading, it looks normal again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I think this is more of a workaround but I got a solution.

I first set all the div's containing my graphs to visible. So it will look all messy and stuff initially.

Then I created a JS code using onLoad:

```
    window.onload = function () {
        mbsTopGraphContainer.style.display = "none";
        mbsBottomGraphContainer.style.display = "none";
        sglTopGraphContainer.style.display = "none";
        sglBottomGraphContainer.style.display = "none";
        fulTopGraphContainer.style.display = "none";
        fulBottomGraphContainer.style.display = "none";
    }
```

where I disable the respective div's that I wanted to hide initially. So all my graphs will be visible and would be loading together, and after it finished loading, the graphs that we don't want to see yet would be hidden.

Comment: To make this look better, you should set their opacity to 0 using CSS, and in the onload function remove the 0 opacity and set the display to none (on the once you want to hide). This will help with the page looking messed up when loading.